# Integrating a mailing list in a discussion group in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, outlook, community-site

Using Sharepoint 2013 community site.

I need to:

1. Send post of a discussion group to a mailing list (outlook users).
2. Answer a thread through mail and replies in a mailing list to a specific

Does anybody had some ideas about how to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am implementing the same thing, It's pretty hard as there is no way OOB and you can't use the sharepoint alerts, i have almost achieved this functionality and everything is working fine [here is a link](http://zeddylabs.com/2013/07/the-ultimate-sharepoint-discussion-board-customization) with which you can start, It implements a event receiver for the Discussion List and generates custom alerts when a new topic is created or a reply is made to an existing thread, It works even if you make actions from UI as well as mail